# for each observe()/listen is equal to one concurrent connection?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider a chat system where one user is listening to multiple parent nodes within one chat conversation.

1. Group title
2. Group description
3. Messages

Does observing/listening to the 3 above mean that it adds up to 3 connections on the 200k concurrency limit? I can't seem to understand the proper definition of a concurrent connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each app (strictly speaking: each `FirebaseDatabase` instance) keeps a single connection to the Firebase Realtime Database server, no many how many listeners it has open.

Also see the [Firebase FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#pricing-simultaneous), which says this about it:

> A simultaneous connection is equivalent to one mobile device, browser tab, or server app connected to the database.